# Checkout from Gitlab is getting fail in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I have read lots of documentation but not able to fix this issue.

I used below code for checkout from gitlab in jenkinfile

```
checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: [
      $class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [[name: "origin/${env.gitlabSourceBranch}"]],
      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
      extensions: [[
        $class: 'PreBuildMerge',
        options: [
          fastForwardMode: 'FF',
          mergeRemote: 'origin',
          mergeStrategy: 'default',
          mergeTarget: "${env.gitlabTargetBranch}"
        ]
      ]],
      submoduleCfg: [],
      userRemoteConfigs: [[
        credentialsId: 'gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials',  
        name: 'origin',
        url: "${env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl}"
      ]]
    ]
```

I even tried

```
checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials', url: 'http://jenkins-master/testproject/devops_artifacts/test_devops.git']]]
```

But I am keep getting this error:

```
    Warning: CredentialId "gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials" could not be found.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository http://gitlab-master.com/testproject/devops_artifacts/test_devops.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init C:\jenkins-docker\workspace\wildfly_gitlab # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://gitlab-master.com/testproject/devops_artifacts/test_devops.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress http://gitlab-master.com/testproject/devops_artifacts/test_devops.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress http://gitlab-master.com/testproject/devops_artifacts/test_devops.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab-master.com/testproject/devops_artifacts/test_devops.git/'
```

I have set webhook in this form

http://username:c4cc893d00cfc8865fc3@10.50.9.XXX:8080/project/wildfly_gitlab

And I tested the connection it is working. Same way I configured Gitlab in Jenkins as well

[image: Jenkins configuration]

And connection is working as well. I don't know why I am still getting the error.

Comment: I have found those issues on Jenkins issues:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58827 and https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60349?attachmentOrder=desc
Unfortunately they are still open, with no real answer or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials" is a user credential (credential scoped to a specific user).

You can circumvent by getting the user credential with `withCredentials` and then using the https with credentials url in the `userRemoteConfigs` config:

```
    parameters {
    credentials(credentialType: 'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl', defaultValue: '', description: 'Jenkins wants to use the "gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials" credentials. Select your credential to allow this.', name: 'gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials', required: true)
}
...

    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials", passwordVariable: 'GITLAB_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GITLAB_USER')]) {
       checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/mytag']], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "https://${GITLAB_USER}:${GITLAB_PASSWORD}@gitlab.com/myproject.git"]]]) 
    }
```

gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials is a user credential of type " Username with password" credential created with:

- id: gitlab-jenkins-user-credentials
- username = gitlab token name
- password = gitlab token

When running the job, the user will be prompted to select it's user credential.

However note that groovy interpolation of secrets is not a good practice on a security point of view (see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation).